# remove view from window give a black screen for a short time

Tags: ios, ios5

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    MyAuraAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAuraAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    // PeopleMasterViewController *peopleMasterViewControl = [[PeopleMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [delegate.window subviews];
    for (InfiniTabBar *v in viewsToRemove) 
    {
        [v setHidden: YES];
    }  

}
```

but before show the other View, it gives me a black screen for a short time. How can I remove the black screen?

Comment: why are you removing the views? what are you trying to do?

Comment: iwant  to hide or remove custom tabbar,i donot want to show in other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the custom tab bar

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [delegate.window subviews];
for (InfiniTabBar *v in viewsToRemove) 
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[InfiniTabBar class]]) {
        [v setHidden: YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code into `viewWillAppear:` so that it's happening closer to the time that the screen is updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other View" in your question?

Comment: i add the tab bar to the window ,in the A page i pressed a button,i want to show the B page,but before B page show,it show black screen for a short time,then show B page.